# Django download excel file results in corrupted Excel file

Tags: django, excel, pandas

I am trying to export a Pandas dataframe from a Django app as an Excel file.   I currently export it to CSV file and this works fine except as noted.   The problem is that when the user open the csv file in Excel App,  a string that looks like numbers .... for example a cell with a value of '111,1112' or '123E345' which is intended to be a string, ends up showing as error or exponent in Excel view; even if I make sure that the Pandas column is not numeric.

This is how I export to CSV:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')  
filename = 'aFileName'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'  
df.to_csv(response, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
return response
```

To export with content type EXCEL, I saw several references where the following approach was recommended:

```
with BytesIO() as b:
        # Use the StringIO object as the filehandle.
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(b, engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        writer.save()
        return HttpResponse(b.getvalue(), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

When I try this, It appears to export something, but if I try to open the file in Excel Office 2016, I get a Excel message that the file is corrupted.  Generally the size is few KB at most.

Please advise what could be wrong with the 2nd approach that is causing a bad export.   I am using Django 2.2.1, Pandas 0.25.1

Thank you

Comment: The content_type is wrong for an xlsx file and you probably need to rewind the buffer. See the example in the xlsxwriter docs: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_django_simple.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference .... the content type and seek did the trick for me.